# Angularjs get sub array id

Tags: angularjs

can someone help me this?
I want to get the person id from the project, and bind it to a link to view more details of the person, but it doesn't look like a multidimensional array to me, any idea?

Angular js:

```
    var projects = [
    {
        id: 1, projectName: 'Economy', year: '2015', projectdescription: 'A cool economy project',
        persons: [
            { person: '1', personId:'1', firstname:'John', lastname:'Snow', description: 'John is an economist', expertise: 'Math' }
        ]
    }
```

Html:

```
<a href="#/projectpersons/{{projects.person.id}}" class="cardBody btn-link">View More</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check my ans it should be the answer according to ur given json

Comment: you need ng-repeat to create your links. please look the code from @AshishRatan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to learn about basic JavaScript stuff:

- `[a, b, c]` (note the square brackets) is an array. You access to the element at index i, starting at 0, using `array[i]`
- `{name: 'Joe', age: 23}` (note the curly brackets) is an object. You access to a property of this object using `object.name` or `object['name']`.

So what you have there is an array of projects. Each project is an object with a `persons` property, holding an array or persons. Each person is an object with a `personId` property.

So, to access the id of the first person of the first project, you would use

```
projects[0].persons[0].personId
```

To access the ID of the second person of the third project, you would use

```
projects[2].persons[1].personId
```

Comment: Sorry, bad coder here. Looks like need a loop to bind each link to each person. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-repeat='pr in projects'>
<div ng-repeat='p in pr.persons'>
{{p.person}}

<a href='#/ur/detail({pId:p.person})'>More detail</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular js:

```
`var projects = [
{
    id: 1, projectName: 'Economy', year: '2015', projectdescription: 'A cool economy project',
    persons: [
        { person: '1', personId:'1', firstname:'John', lastname:'Snow', description: 'John is an economist', expertise: 'Math' }
    ]
}`
```

html:

```
`<a href="#/projectpersons/{{projects[0].person[0].personId}}" class="cardBody btn-link">View More</a>`
```